# How to import a CSV calendar into my Google Calendars, using java

Tags: java, csv, import, google-calendar-api, gdata

I would like to know how to import a CSV calendar into my Google Calendars, using java as programming language.

It should be a way since the web service offers this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Use a program you would need to:

1. Read the CSV calendar file
2. For each event in the CSV file, use the Calendar insert API provided by Google (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert)

That's pretty high level, but it's the gist of how it would be done using a program.

Comment: you will hit a "Rate Limit Exceeded" with this method pretty quickly